# Unity Game Object Controlled by real light spot on the wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

We have got various controllers developed for moving gameobjects. I have used magnetometer/gyro sensor to move game object using MUVSlide through following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using ForestIndieGames.Muvslide;

public class Connection : MonoBehaviour {

    private static bool created = false;

    private bool newInputAvailable;
    private MuvslideConnection muvslideConn;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!created)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            created = true;
            muvslideConn = new MuvslideConnection();
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (muvslideConn != null)
            muvslideConn.Close();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (muvslideConn.GetInputManager().IsNewMotionAvailable())
            newInputAvailable = true;
    }

    public bool IsNewInputAvailable()
    {
        bool result = newInputAvailable;
        newInputAvailable = false;
        return result;
    }

    public Vector3 GetAngles()
    {
        float[] angles = muvslideConn.GetInputManager().GetOrientationDegrees();
        return new Vector3(angles[0], angles[1], angles[2]);
    }

}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to move a gameobject by a real light spot on the wall. The spot is on the wall and fed through a camera. When the spot moves I want game object to follow exactly. The light spot can be a specific color or IR or UV etc. 
Any leads please

Comment: The fact that it is fed through the camera may help you out.  You can Raycast from the camera. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraRays.html

Comment: How do you get the camera's image on each frame? Is it as a Texture2D or something else?

Comment: Search for "OpenCV laser tracking".  Buy an openCV asset from the asset store and port one the search results to C#, or wrap one of them in a native plugin and use it as is.

Comment: @LeoBartkus: Just fabulous. I got it working now in python opencv and trying to import data into unity. but that part seems to be very hard....trying with some unity asset...i will let you know how it goes...thanks a lot

Comment: @LeoBartkus thanks for your suggestion. I successfully integrated opencv with unity. And its tracking light. Only issue is there us lagging. As i have to cast the scene on wall using projector, there is   a lag between target and what is cast on the wall on target. Any lead to overcome lagging?

Comment: I would look to see if using different parameters for findContours() helps.  If the problem is the game's framerate, I would try throttling the calls to do the tracking, and see if it makes a difference.  Another thing to try would be breaking the image capture and tracking off into its own thread, and only doing synchronization in the game object's update.  I would probably avoid trying to use object velocity to predict its real location, but that's another option.

Comment: Oh, and of course you could also try to trade accuracy for speed by lowering the resolution of the image you are capturing.